# Extract monthly data from a list with mean greater than a threshold using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two csv files with two columns each (have 10 years of daily data):

```
time,value
19800101,0.15
.
.
.
```

I used following to read data in lists `a` and `b`

```
import csv

a = []
with open('data.csv','rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        a.append([row[0],row[1]])
```

same way to get list `b`. I want to get mean of each month in list `a` and if it falls below 0.01 then remove all daily values belonging to that month and output a new list. Also, I want corresponding daily values to be removed from list `b` as well to produce a new list for it. Both lists `a` and `b` would be of equal length with same time steps.
Any suggestions would be appreciative.

For example:

```
a = [0.14,1.12........] # daily values (say have 2-years = 730 values)
b = [0.11,0.005,......] # daily values (say have 2-years = 730 values)
```

if March and April have monthly mean less than 0.01 in list `a` then will get following lists with daily values for these months removed:

```
a_new = [0.14,1.12,.....] # daily values (669 values)
b_new = [0.11,0.005,....] # daily values (669 values)
```

Comment: can you explain this `want to get mean of each month in list a`

Comment: Get mean of each month separately using daily data values and remove daily data records from list if monthly mean is less than 0.01

Comment: can you show some expected input and expected output

Comment: I haven't worked out full solution but I believe you need to keep the time stamp column as well to detect month change: `a.append([row[0],row[1]])`

Comment: @Jason: thanks. yeah I need to have time step part of the lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this may not be a quite good-looking and most effcient solution... but let me know how it works.

```
import numpy,csv

time=[]
data_a=[]
data_b=[]

#--------------------Read in a--------------------
with open('data_a.csv','rb') as csvfile:
    reader=csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        time.append(row[0])
        data_a.append(float(row[1]))

#--------------------Read in b--------------------
with open('data_b.csv','rb') as csvfile:
    reader=csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        data_b.append(float(row[1]))

data_a=numpy.array(data_a)
data_b=numpy.array(data_b)
monthly=numpy.zeros(data_a.shape)

#-----------------Get month means-----------------
for ii in xrange(len(time)):
    tt=time[ii]
    if ii==0:
        month_old=tt[4:6]
        index_start=ii
    else:
        #----------------new month----------------
        month=tt[4:6]
        if month != month_old:
            month_mean=numpy.mean(data_a[index_start:ii])
            print 'mean for month',month_old,month_mean
            monthly[index_start:ii]=month_mean
            month_old=month
            index_start=ii

    #----------------Get the last month----------------
    if ii==len(time)-1:
        month_mean=numpy.mean(data_a[index_start:])
        print 'mean for month',month_old,month_mean
        monthly[index_start:]=month_mean

#-------------------Filter data-------------------
index=numpy.where(monthly>=0.01)
data_a_filtered=numpy.take(data_a,index)
data_b_filtered=numpy.take(data_b,index)
time_filtered=numpy.take(time,index)
```

Comment: Thanks. I got following error while running above code:
`return mean(axis, dtype, out)
TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type`

Comment: which line is it? Is it the `numpy.mean()` function? I got this too when debugging and solved it after changing the data format to floats by adding the float conversion `data_a.append(float(row[1]))`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. One more thing: If I process filtered and non-filtered data separately and would like to join them back in same time series order as original. Would it be possible?

Comment: @lbe Yes. In that case: `data_a_filtered=numpy.ma.masked_where(monthly<0.01,data_a)`. Process this masked array. To join with the original daily data: `new=numpy.where(monthly<0.01,data_a_filtered,data_a)`.

Comment: I have sorted this array data_a_filtered and modified values. Is it possible to break this array into monthly array of arrays `[[month1],[month2],...]`?

Comment: I guess you have to loop through the time axis again and detect month change like we did previously. Refer back to the code I posted and try to modify it.